# Can't add item to array via variable: is not defined at <top-level>,

Tags: bash, jq

In bash script:

```
for (( pageNumber=$page; pageNumber<=$countPages; pageNumber++ ))         
do
    read -r currentIssuesArr < <(echo $(curl -s -XGET $BASE_URL/issues/search\?componentKeys\=$PROJECT_KEY\&p\=$pageNumber\&ps\=$PAGE_SIZE | jq -r '.issues[]'))
    jq '.issues[.issues| length] |= . + {"aaaaaaaaaaaa": "2010-01-07T19:55:99.999Z"}' $FILE_REPORT_RESULT >test.json
done
```

This work fine. And add json to last array's item. Nice.

But now I want do the same but via variable `currentIssuesArr`

Like this:

```
for (( pageNumber=$page; pageNumber<=$countPages; pageNumber++ ))         
do
    read -r currentIssuesArr < <(echo $(curl -s -XGET $BASE_URL/issues/search\?componentKeys\=$PROJECT_KEY\&p\=$pageNumber\&ps\=$PAGE_SIZE | jq -r '.issues[]'))
    jq '.issues[.issues| length] |= . + $currentIssuesArr' $FILE_REPORT_RESULT >test.json
done
```

But now I get error:

```
jq: error: $currentIssuesArr is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.issues[.issues| length] |= . + $currentIssuesArr                                
jq: 1 compile error
jq: error: $currentIssuesArr is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
```

Comment: Variables are not expanded inside single quotes in `bash`. Try using double quotes and escape whatever needs to be escaped.

Comment: Don't inject variables from outside into the code! Rather import their values using the `--arg` or `--argjson` options.

Comment: Unrelated: did you mean `.issues |= . + $currentIssuesArr` to just append the issues?

Comment: ... or just `.issues += $currentIssuesArr`

Answer (score 0):

You set the shell's `currentIssuesArr` but not `jq`'s. Use:

```sh
jq --argjson currentIssuesArr "$currentIssuesArr" '...'
```

You could also export `currentIssuesArr` and use `env.currentIssuesArr` in `jq`.

If we cleanup the program, we get

```
jq --argjson currentIssuesArr "$currentIssuesArr" '.issues += [ $currentIssuesArr ]'
```

(You call the variable an "issues array", but your working code shows an object. If it is an array, remove the square brackets.)

Comment: This work :   jq -r ".issues[.issues| length] |= . + $currentIssuesArr"

Comment: @a_subscriber, No. Do not generate jq code from the shell. (Also, the `-r` makes no sense, and the program is overly complicated. See update)